# Does Konan have a theme song?

Tags: naruto, theme-song

Pretty much every character in Naruto seems to have his/her own theme song. But I can't seem to find a theme song for [Konan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Konan). Does she just not have one? or is it just hard to find/ not released yet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Konan - as far as I know - doesn't have an official soundtrack. She's usually seen with Pain in which Pain's soundtrack plays.

I'd say that Konan shares a soundtrack with Pain which is called Girei.

Answer (score -2):

Theres a song in the storm revolution game thats starts when konan talks to sasori i think thats here theme

Answer (score -3):

there is one called the angelic herald of death which is associated usually with konan it is an unreleased OST